# Grid lines behind div without using absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a time selector that:

1. Sits inside a scrollable div (`overflow-y:scroll`)
2. Has an interactive click-and-drag area
3. Has a grid of 25 single-pixel lines behind the interactive area
4. Stretches vertically to fit any selected height

[image: Example]

*(This example image incorrectly shows the grid lines not perfectly aligned with the time markers to the left, so just pretend they do)*

Accompanying codepen: http://codepen.io/t3db0t/pen/VKROka (non-interactive)

Previously I had this all working with absolute positioning, but that wreaked havoc with scrolling (as in, you couldn't use the mouse wheel to scroll the div, which is a requirement).  So I have everything working without absolute positioning except for the grid lines.

I could do a repeating pattern or image, but then it would not stretch vertically correctly.  The number of lines will always be the same.  Any ideas?

Comment: any html and css with your screenshot ? linear-gradient, line-height, rem, background-size could be a combination to start with ....

Comment: You probably should still use position absolute relative to a parent that is not affected by scrolling. That should not be an issue, unless there's something weird in your code that we can't see anyways.

Comment: You can use `:after` pseudo-element. Of course you will will use `absolute` positioning but relative to the parent.

Comment: I might have to try again, but I found that in Chrome at least, anything `absolute` would not respond to the scroll wheel if the mouse was over it...?

Comment: Added codepen showing current state that scrolls correctly

Comment: Please don't add a link to your code that demonstrates your problem, include that code in the question so that, when the external link dies for whatever reason, your question remains self-contained, and understandable. Although linking to a demo is a bonus, it doesn't replace the necessity of including your code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. The parent was not positioned correctly, and it was causing the child to somehow intercept the scrolling in an undesirable way, so I am now using the absolute-positioned, layered divs to show the grid lines.  Harun's answer is intriguing, but I wasn't able to get it to work exactly as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this using a repeating linear gradient.  The trick is to use percentages that divide into the number of lines that you want.  if you want a total of 25 sections then your last gradient stop should be 4% (4% x 25 = 100%).
you can position your line anywhere within the gradient by placing color stops on top of eachother.

The line will not be one pixel but a percentage of the whole width. There are some cross browser rendering issues that can cause the width of the line to vary. However under the right circumstances this can be a great solution.

Keep in mind that this divides the contianer into 25 sections ... not 26 sections divided by 25 lines.  if you want that your gradient would have to be 3.85% (100 / 26)

My code example places the line at the begining of the repeated gradient, the link below places it in the middle

http://www.virtuosoft.eu/tools/css-gradient-generator/?t=linear&d=angle&r=on&a=0&sp=00000000_0_%25__00000000_1.7_%25__000000_1.7_%25__000000_2.3_%25__00000000_2.3_%25__00000000_4_%25

```css
.gradient {
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,black 0%,black 0.5%,transparent 0.5%,transparent 4%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(0deg,black 0%,black 0.5%,transparent 0.5%,transparent 4%);
    background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,black 0%,black 0.5%,transparent 0.5%,transparent 4%);
}
```

Comment: Hm, this is super interesting, and getting close to an ideal solution... But sadly if I can't guarantee single-pixel lines it won't work :(

Comment: Also I can't seem to get this quite right.  The repetition comes in clumps of 3  lines separated by a larger space... not sure why this is happening

Comment: (I meant: if I lower the middle stops from 0.5 to 0.1 I can get a nice single pixel line, but then...)

Comment: another approach would be set the height for the commented (.availabilitySelectorMarker currently set to height 40px) elements in percentages. which you can do as long as the parent element has a static pixel height set.  If that element has to adjust you can use jQuery to set height to a static value dynamically.  Check out matchHeight https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height . Its a great plugin that solves a lot of issues. But it also happens to set a static pixel height based on the elements auto height.  this value is recalculated on resize and you can trigger a recalculation with JS

Comment: Lots of ways to skin a cat i guess